# How can I convert a double to a long in java while keeping all the double's bits?

Tags: java, double, long-integer, endianness

I need to convert a double to an array of bytes in little endian, keeping the decimal places. To do this, I need to use bitwise operations on the double. However, I cannot do >> or & to a double. Since long is the only other type that can be used in bitwise operations and is 64bit, I need to convert a double to a long in such a way that:

`011010101010.1001010010100101001010010100101001010010100101001010`

becomes

`011010101010 1001010010100101001010010100101001010010100101001010L`

instead of

`000000000000 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000011010101010L`

Comment: Since this is NOT a duplicate of that question, I will answer in a comment.  Use the static method  `Double.doubleToLongBits(yourDouble)`.  Or perhaps the doubleToRawLongBits variant.  Except I'm not sure this is what you want???

Comment: @user949300 If it isn't a duplicate, how come your answer appears there?

Comment: How are you going to represent/manage the binary point location - indicated by a space in your example output?

Comment: @EJP Because you changed the link in the "already has an answer here" section.  The original link went to a different question.  I agree that the new, corrected link is indeed a duplicate.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I won't. The purpose of the space was to line up the binary digits.